# How to print image in thermal printer using Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, printers, thermal-printer

I need to print a image using thermal printer. Now I am able to print text using below code,

```
private fun printBill() {
        Thread {
            try {
                val sock = Socket("192.168.100.99", 9100)
                val oStream = PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream())
                oStream.printf("%-35s %-5s %5s\n", "Jihin Raju", 10.00, 100.00)
                oStream.println(charArrayOf(0x1D.toChar(), 0x56.toChar(), 0x41.toChar(), 0x10.toChar()))
                oStream.close()
                sock.close()
            } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Printed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Is there any way to print image

Comment: I think it depends on the printer model and the protocol that shall be used. I think there's no general protocol for thermal printers.

Comment: I second Christopher it depends on the printer make and model